# How to train huge ML model on multiple budget machines on web?

Tags: distributed, neural-network, deep-learning

Is there a way to train huge models (1+ TiB of parameter data) being distributed on web? For example, I have a several hundreds of budget machines, each equipped with 2-4 GiB of RAM and with no powerful GPU. Is there a ready developed software that supports this scenario?

If such a software doesn't exist could you point to some relevant researches?